# Does Wolfram's MathWorld describe a different kind of ordinal multiplication?

Tags: ordinals

According to [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrdinalMultiplication.html),

> If $\beta$ is a limit ordinal, then $\alpha*\beta$ is the least ordinal greater than any ordinal in the set $\{\,\alpha*\gamma:\gamma<\beta\,\}$ (Suppes 1972, p. 212).

So with $\beta=\omega$ and $\alpha=0$, we see that $\{\,0*n:n<\omega\,\}=\{0\}$  and would infer that $0* \omega=1$.
This seems to be a weird claim (and backed up by literature?), given that the definition via lexical ordering of cartesian products clearly results in $\alpha*0=0*\alpha=0$ for all $\alpha$.

Is that just a typo or are there competing definitions of ordinal multiplication that differ in this respect common?

Comment: I suppose "greater than" is to be understood as "greater than or equal to" here.

Comment: My guess is that they tried expressing $\sup\{\alpha*\gamma: \gamma<\beta\}$ in words and got things mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

They mean to define $\alpha \ast \beta$ for every fixed $\alpha$ by recursion on $\beta$.

So we need a starting clause $\alpha \ast 0 = 0$.

A successor clause: $\alpha \ast (\beta+1) = \alpha \ast \beta + \beta$, also no problem.

A limit clause (but in words it was messed up):

For a limit ordinal $\beta$, such that $\alpha \ast \gamma$ is defined for all $\gamma < \beta$:

$$\alpha \ast \beta = \sup \{\alpha \ast \gamma: \gamma < \beta\}$$

and all is well in the world. It's now easy to show that $0 \times \omega = 0$ as it ought to be.

It's an interesting exercise now to show that this coincides with the more direct way of defining it by taking the order type of $\alpha \times \beta$ in reverse lexicographic order ($(x,y) <(u,v)$ iff $ y < v$, or $y=v$ and $x < u$).